# How to make 2 <Text> inline in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to make 2  in one line, one `flex-end` and one `flex-start`, but I am not able to make it inline after applying `flex-end` and `flex-start` to the two  separately. Anyone have idea how to do this?

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>Line 1</Text>
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>Line 2</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `justifyContent:'space-between'` and you are done, no need to use anything in `Text`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
   <Text>Line 1</Text>
   <Text>Line 2</Text>
</View>
```